# What are the lyrics to I Signori Della Galassia's 'Sub'?

Tags: lyrics

Not sure if asking for lyrics in their entirety is generally acceptable here, but I've scoured using my best Italian (which isn't saying much) and have rendered no fruit.

Anybody know/understand the Italian lyrics of this song:

['Sub' by I Signori Della Galassia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JB7pvwiUqgE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not found any official lyrics, but listening to the song that's what I've come across.
(Note: I'm Italian, so the lyrics should be ok, except for a word or two)

> 20 metri / Acqua chiara / Vado ancora più giù
>
> Dondolando / Sopra bolle / Nell’immenso nel blu
>
> 100 metri / Quanto buio / Ma una luce laggiù
>
> Un sentiero / Di rugida / Che si apre per me

---

> (Chorus)
>
> Il tempo di un respiro e poi volare / Sentire più lontane le mie paure / Ed esser preso per mano (gabbiano che va - ?) / Ora non sono più solo dopo il riposo

---

> Padre mio / Questa casa / Sembra fatta da te
>
> La mia stanza / La mia culla / Canta ancora per me
>
> Silenziosa / Dolce sposa / Al tuo seno verrò
>
> Che il tramonto / Sia il mio dono / Quando a te giungerò

---

> (Chorus)